# Reaction Commerce deployment to Heroku failing, boot_proxy.js not generated

Tags: heroku, meteor, reaction-commerce

I was trying to set up a running instance running on Heroku by following [these](https://docs.reactioncommerce.com/docs/deploying-reaction-using-heroku) instructions. All goes well but after the build is finished, an error occurs and the app crashed.

```
Error: Cannot find module /app/.meteor/heroku_build/bin/boot_proxy.js
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
 at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
 at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
 at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
Process exited with status 1
```

This is the content of the Procfile.

```
web: .meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/bin/boot_proxy.js .meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/main.js
```

I used heroku bash to explore the app and saw that The file `boot_proxy.js` is not being generated. Does anyone know a fix to this? Already filed a bug on git repo.

Answer (score 2):

As it can be found in [this forked repo](https://github.com/Zanobo/reaction-buildpack) the missing `boot_proxy.js` comes from a overdue startup of reaction:

> Sometimes reaction takes too much time to start and Heroku thinks that there's a problem with your app. To sidestep this we have a simple proxy that answers every request until it's ready.

https://github.com/Zanobo/reaction-buildpack#boot-proxy

So in order to fix the issue, you should use this fork at the buildpack step:

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/Zanobo/reaction-buildpack.git
```

and add this environment variable in Heroku:

```
USE_BOOT_PROXY=1
```